# How to insert values to adjacent cells in Excel

Tags: excel

Basically, I have an Excel spreadsheet that looks like this

```
job | timesteps | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
 1        2
 2        3
 3        4
```

I need to fill the cells to the right of the timestep column row values with the value "R" that corresponds to the timestep row value. It needs to look something like this.

```
job | timesteps | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
 1        2       R   R                         
 2        3       R   R   R
 3        4       R   R   R
```

For example, in job 1, which takes 2 timesteps, thus there are 2 "R"s in the next two cells on the same row.

Please can anyone offer any insight as to what Excel formula is needed to achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple IF comparing the return of a column() with the number will suffice:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)<=$B2,"R","")
```

Put in your upper left cell, then copy/drag over and down the return value area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your verbal description does not match your example. Following your verbal description, you need to keep track of start and end in your if statement:

```
=IF(AND(C$1>=$A2,C$1<=$A2+$B2-1),"R","")
```